# How should I display my checked results in different component?

Tags: arrays, angular, checkbox, duplicates

I have two checkboxes called slack and teams. If I check slack I want slack image to be displayed on different component. I almost made it but it's displaying both slack and teams. Please have a look at my image, you may get idea what I am trying to ask

[image: Here I selected one checkbox]

But the results are

[image: it's displaying both]

html(second-component)

```
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class=" card-collapse border p-3 mb-4" id="accordion" role="tablist" *ngFor="let data of slackNteamsData">
      <div class=" py-3" *ngIf="data.config_code == 'slack'">
        <div class=" collapsed" id="headingOne">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" [attr.aria-expanded]="!collapseOne"
          data-toggle="collapse" (click)="collapseOne = !collapseOne" id="collapseOne" href="#pablo">
            <div class="pr-3 slack-img">
              <img src="{{ asseturl('/images/slack-img.png') }}" alt="icon" >
            </div>
            <div>
              <strong class="d-block">Slack Integration</strong>
              <small class="text-muted">Get notified in Slack for new Backlog activity such as comments</small>
            </div>
            <a class="ml-auto" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class=" tim-icons icon-minimal-down ml-auto"> </i></a>
          </div>
        </div>.

 <div class=" py-3" *ngIf="data.config_code == 'teams'">
        <div class="collapsed" id="headingTwo">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center" aria-controls="collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" [attr.aria-expanded]="!collapseTwo"
          (click)="collapseTwo = !collapseTwo" id="collapseTwo" href="#pablo">
            <div class="pr-3 slack-img">
              <img src="{{ asseturl('/images/teams-ms.png') }}" alt="icon" >
            </div>
            <div>
              <strong class="d-block">Teams Integration</strong>
              <small class="text-muted">Get notified in Teams for new Backlog activity such as comments</small>
            </div>
            <a class="ml-auto" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class=" tim-icons icon-minimal-down ml-auto"> </i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is my response:

```
[{
    id: 193,
    config_code: "teams",
    config_value: "false"
},
{
    id: 194,
    config_code: "stack",
    config_value: "true"
},
{
    id: 195,
    config_code: "stack",
    config_value: "true"
},
{
    id: 196,
    config_code: "teams",
    config_value: "false"
}]
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain what you have tried, with codes?

Comment: Yeah Sure,I will add my code there,Its very lenghthy code. I will explain here.
I have created form in one component and posting by setting values true or false. And in another component,using get call i am returning those images using ngif condition

Comment: I have added getcall code there

Comment: share your api response.

Comment: Sure, I have added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all items which have `config_value` as 'true' (string as in response) and distinct by `config_code`

```
this.response = this.response.filter(item => item.config_value ==='true');

this.response = [...new Set(this.response.map(item => item.config_code))]
.map(i => this.response.find(item => item.config_code == i));
```

Comment: Great, it worked, Thank you